# NUnit: Unit testing, recommendations on storing test data files

Tags: unit-testing, junit, nunit, mstest

I've started working on an OpenXml based engine, and we are using a lot of pptx files for testing purpose. we do not want these files to be stored in the source control. is there any recommendations on this. may be storing in a network share or a mapped drive etc?

Comment: Why don't you want to store the files in the source control?

Comment: i didn't want the SCM to grow larger coz of binaries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not store the test files in source control?  Clearly, the are part of the test suite, so they belong with the tests.

Think of it this way: you write the test to discover if there is something wrong with your code.  If the code is passing the test now, it might fail if you change the code itself, or the test (including the test files that drive the test).  So you want to keep the test files with the test in the source control, so you have control over what tests are executed exactly.

As time goes on, you might change these files to better reflect the changes in requirements.  At this point you do not want to juggle with which version of the test files belong to which version of the source/test code, which would happen if you kept them separately

Comment: Thanks.. only reason i wanted it out of SCM is that binaries might make the SCM grow larger. but your points are valid :)

Comment: Unless you have _huge_ binaries and a ton of them, disk space should not be a problem nowadays

Answer (score 3):

The logical place to store them is in version control. That way you can modify them without worrying about breaking previous versions of your test code. Storing them on a network share will be a constant cause of problems. Your version control system will log each and every change to the files along with who did it. Your network share is unlikely to provide a similar facility. If you are concerned about the size of the files, and whether your version control system will cope, get a decent version control system.

Comment: One thing we do with external files needed in tests is to embed the files into the test assembly as an  embedded resource. The only downside is that the assembly can get quite large but we haven't found that to be a major problem. Certainly better to be able to move a test assembly around knowing that all of its dependencies are resolvable inside itself than then having to worry about a set of external files as well.

Comment: Why do you need to move a test assembly?

Comment: We use TeamCity to build our artifacts, it zips them up and moves them around the various builds in order that we don't need to constantly rebuild the source code. By placing the test artifacts inside the test assemblies we don't then also need to copy those artifacts alongside the test assemblies. Just another thing that can go wrong.